# Set Cassandra properties for spark-cassandra-connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

How do I set the following properties for the `spark-cassandra-connector` version `2.0.7`:

1. `cassandra.pool.remote.coreConnectionsPerHost`
2. `cassandra.allowRemoteDcsForLocalConsistencyLevel`

Essentially I want to set it up so that there should be 0 connected clients to my remote dc and there should also be 0 reads/writes.  Everything should be local to the DC I'm are running in.

Does setting `spark.cassandra.connection.local_dc` to a local DC achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is the default behavior of the connector. I got my answer at https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md#inter-datacenter-communication-is-forbidden-by-default